# Opposite of "out of date"?

Tags: phrases, expressions, expression-choice

Can anyone think of a phrase we would use to describe a situation where something is the opposite of "out of date"; that is, it's "too new"?

For example, a banana that's been sitting around for ages and is inedible could be described as "out of date", but a green banana that's not yet ripe is at the opposite end of the spectrum.  Another example might be an engine part that is too old for a particular model of car; it would be "out of date".  But what about if the car is old enough that the part's design has been updated since the car's manufacture, and the replacement part would now be "too new" to operate with the car's engine?

Obviously one way to deal with this latter situation is to turn the sentence round and descibe the *car* as "out of date", but is there a succinct way to keep the "too new" object as the subject of the sentence and describe it as the opposite of "out of date"?

Comment: Is the car part analogy a real life situation? It seems unreal to me, since spare parts are designed and manufactured to meet the specifications of a particular engine. A spare part would only be "too new" if the compatible engine were not yet on the market.

Comment: @GoodA.M. Substitute a computer part, then. An out-of-date computer with an out-of-date architecture may not support newer hardware, which is thus ‘not yet in date’.

Comment: Postdated as in a check that can't be cashed.

Comment: Actually, "green" is a good word for the item of produce, banana or not, and the term is understood in other contexts as well, as "green employee".  "Immature" is another word.

Comment: Couldn't up-to-date do?

Comment: The banana situation and the car part situation are sufficiently different that most good terms won't work for both. They aren't analogous either — the banana will be fine when it eventually ripens, but the car part will still be incompatible.

Comment: What @200_success said. As it stands, the question is either Unclear or Too Broad.

Comment: The banana is _not yet ripe_. As you say. The replacement part is _not backwards compatible_.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way is to use ***Not yet in date.***

That can be used with things like coupons which have a validity period which hasn't yet been reached. *In date* is a direct opposite of *out of date* (that is, it says that something is valid); but where *out of date* implies expiry has already happened, using *not yet* implies something is still to happen.

While this does work for coupons with a start date, it won't work with the example of the car part. But in that case, I wouldn't say the car engine is "out of date" either. The engine's design is simply too old for the part; or the part's design is too new for the engine.

Comment: Can I say : "College admission is still in date."?

Answer (score 15):

***[Premature](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/premature)*** implies a thing that is before its time.

> The green banana is *premature* until it ripens.
>
> The coupon is *premature* until the start date.
>
> The spare part is *premature* for an engine that has not been introduced on the market.

Alternately as suggested by ScotM

***[Post-dated](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/post-date?q=postdated)***

> The new part for an old engine is post-dated.

Answer (score 9):

As for the banana example, the descriptor would be:

> "An **unripe** banana is green"

To describe the car part that's "too new" for the old engine, one of the most common descriptors is **modern**, as in:

> "We just can't fix this engine with **modern** parts"

Alternatively, the most accurate descriptor is either **postcontemporary** or **ultracontemporary**. Contemporary itself is an adjective used to describe things as belonging to the same time. **Postcontemporary** indicates that an object exists at a later time than what it is compared to. **Ultracontemporary** Indicates an object exists in the latest, or most modern time possible. So the best way to say it (if not the most colloquial) would be:

> "The engine cannot be fixed with **postcontemporary** spare parts, especially not the **ultracontemporary** ones."

To keep this going, other antonyms of out-dated might include (depending on context):

- Post-modern
- Futuristic
- Not backwards-compatible
- Fresh
- Trendy
- ... any more and I become a thesaurus

Comment: +1 for **contemporary**. That's the first word that comes to mind when I think of the opposite of “out of date.”

Comment: **Current** would be my second choice.

Answer (score 8):

It depends a bit on what you're describing exactly – things can be "up and coming", "avant garde" or "cutting edge" (or "bleeding edge", in particular in IT, if you're not sure it will last or is useful). If you disapprove of the new thing, it can be "newfangled".

Comment: You can hurt yourself out on the bleeding edge. Some of those adrenaline junkies push it *past* the envelope, and damn the consequences.

Answer (score 4):

In the case of the car part, you could say that it is not [backwards-compatible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backward_compatibility).

From that term, it is understood that the part has been updated (otherwise we'd simply say it was not compatible or was incompatible) and that the updated part does not work acceptably with older versions of the mating equipment.

Answer (score 3):

The opposite of "out-of-date" is *futuristic*.

But in the sense that you mean, "too new", that would be covered by *incompatible* or *no longer compatible*.

Answer (score 1):

One way to say  it -  **"soon to become trendy"**

You could also say

- "soon to become fashionable"
- "soon to be released"
- "soon to hit the winning basket"
- "soon to become popular"

Answer (score 1):

We can say something is "not ready for prime time".   It can be an "alpha" version or a "prototype". It can be "untried" or "untested". It can even be "too new" or "fresh from the drawing board". To better answer your question we would need to know the domain.

Comment: Beta as in development?

Answer (score 1):

The popular phrase for things that are generally thought of in that light is, *"Ahead of its time"*

Answer (score 0):

How about **current**?

> Version 5.1 of the software is outdated. You should update to version 6, which is **current**.

There's also **in vogue** but it generally only applies to fashion styles.

> Bell-bottoms are no longer **in vogue**.

Answer (score 0):

Out-of-date *implies* that something is *no longer* popular or applicable.  Ergo, then when it *was* useful the words `in-date`, `popular` or `fad` are all antonyms for out-of-date.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Michaelangelo. 
We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Can you edit your post to explain how it answers the question?

Comment: "Brevity is the wit of the soul".  Expecting an over-engineered verbose answer is a problem, not a "solution".  The answer is fine `as-is`.

Answer (score 0):

The **logical opposite** of "out of date" is "up to date", however, the possible phrases for what you are looking for (phrase that do not include "current") is "pre-dated", "ahead of one's/its time".

Other similar expressions include "state of the art".

**out dated**
out of date; obsolete.
synonyms:   old-fashioned, out of date, outmoded, out of fashion, unfashionable, dated, passé, old, behind the times, behindhand, obsolete, antiquated; More

**pre date**
past tense: pre-dated; past participle: pre-dated
exist or occur at a date earlier than (something).
"this letter predates her illness"

**ahead of one's (or its) time**
innovative and radical by the standards of the time; more characteristic of a later age.
synonyms:   revolutionary, avant-garde, futuristic, innovatory, innovative, trailblazing, pioneering, groundbreaking, advanced, cutting edge
"Leonardo was ahead of his time in almost all endeavors"

Answer (score 0):

Given modern sensibilities with technology you could also use the development terms of **alpha** or **beta** as these have definite connotations that the thing that is 'in alpha' or 'in beta' is not yet fully developed.  When working with technology these terms can apply to just about anything, and you could easily spread their use to other creative developments such as "I'm writing a new song, but I don't want to share it just yet as the lyrics are still in alpha."

Another term I don't think I saw in the previous answers is 'premature' depending on what context you have.

Answer (score -1):

You could be snarky and describe it as "pre-obsolescent."

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Missy. 
When you have enough [rep](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) such a short post could be made as a comment.

Comment: ... and until that time it should not be made at all!